# SMB share/Hyper-V - error 551 and error 1009

Tags: hyper-v, network-share, server-message-block

Setup:
Hypervisors:

- HV1 (Server 2019)
- HV2 (Server 2019)

Storage:

- Storage0 (Server 2019)
- Storage1 (Server 2019)

From the above -- you can see i have two file and two HV servers. I'm trying to use SMB as the protocol to host the VM's storage. I have permissions on the share set as:

> Name ScopeName AccountName AccessControlType AccessRight
>
> > VMs Everyone Allow Full
> >
> > VMs HOME\Domain Admins Allow Full
> >
> > VMs HOME\HV1$ Allow Full
> >
> > VMs HOME\HV2$ Allow Full

However -- when I do a VM storage move or even set up a new vm on the share, i get the following message in event viewer:

> The server denied anonymous access to the client.
>
> Client Name: \x.x.x.x Client Address: x.x.x.x:58666 Session ID:
> 0x200054000021
>
> Guidance:
>
> You should expect this error when a client attempts to connect to
> shares and does not provide any credentials. This indicates that the
> client is not providing a user name (and domain credentials, if
> necessary). By default, Windows Server denies anonymous access to
> shares.
>
> This error does not always indicate a problem with authorization, but
> mainly authentication. It is more common with non-Windows clients.

> SMB Session Authentication Failure
>
> Client Name: \x.x.x.x Client Address: x.x.x.x:58666 User Name: NT
> AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON Session ID: 0x200054000021 Status: {Access
> Denied} A process has requested access to an object, but has not been
> granted those access rights. (0xC0000022) SPN: session setup failed
> before the SPN could be queried SPN Validation Policy: SPN optional /
> no validation
>
> Guidance:
>
> You should expect this error when attempting to connect to shares
> using incorrect credentials.
>
> This error does not always indicate a problem with authorization, but
> mainly authentication. It is more common with non-Windows clients.
>
> This error can occur when using incorrect usernames and passwords with
> NTLM, mismatched LmCompatibility settings between client and server,
> an incorrect service principal name, duplicate Kerberos service
> principal names, incorrect Kerberos ticket-granting service tickets,
> or Guest accounts without Guest access enabled

I am able to manually move the files over SMB using the same domain account I'm using to move through Hyper-V manager.

Is there any advice I can get to make this work besides going iSCSI?

Comment: create a new cluster and use a cluster volume